# "Error watching file for changes: EMFILE" when run the examples from facebook/react-native/Examples

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to run the Examples from facebook/react-native/Examples in OS X 10.12.

First I use `npm install` and then use `npm start`:

There is an error:

```
Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
{"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"Error watching file for changes:","filename":null}
Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1406:11)
```

Then I use Xcode run the code but there is the same error.

I need help or advice. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The react-native-cli depends on watchman, you can try to install watchman with `brew install watchman`,then have another try.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me: 
`brew install watchman`